# Can't access unallocated disk space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, unallocated

[image]

I had two OSes, I tried to delete Windows and keep the Ubuntu.

I tried to delete  my Windows partition to have some extra space in my Ubuntu drive. After deleting the partition for the Windows I can't use that space. That is still showing unallocated when ever I am trying to access that it's not happening.

Answer (score 1):

To use that unallocated space, you can create a new partition from that (right-click on it).

Or you could extend the other partition (sda6 in your case) using the Resize/Move option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed your Ubuntu with LVM, you could create an extra partition and add that to the LVM volume or you can boot you computer with a gparted live cd/usb and resize you partition the gui way.